# Why are racing catamarans' hulls not teardrop shaped?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag

Looking at the America's Cup 72 class catamarans, I was wondering about their hull shape, which has a sharp wave piercing bow. My question is: since an airfoil shape experiences less drag than a sharp triangular one, why does the AC72 catamaran design have the latter? Does it have something to do with wave drag or with the speed of those boats?

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question is unclear, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think piercing the waves gives more pitch (backward/frontward) stability. If a big wave hits the bow then you do not want your bow rapidly forced upwards and you **really don't want** your bow to be forced downwards which can lead to pitch pole capsizing.

The most common capsize in sailing is for the boat to be pushed onto its side, but sailing boats can nose-dive into waves and pitch-pole capsize. The bow goes into the water and the stern goes up in the air. Pitch-pole capsizes are, I believe, more nasty than regular capsizes, particularly on such complicated catamarans.

Comment: The issue with catamarans is the water-plane area. As long as both pontoons are in the water, there is a large area and a significant righting-arm. If one pontoon leaves the water, water-plane area is suddenly and discontinuously reduced to a much smaller area. This suddenly reduces the righting arm and accelerates the instability. I also agree the bow design - probably to reduce the chance of pitch-poling.

Comment: @docscience sorry but if one pontoon lifts from the water the righting moment is greater not smaller, since all the righting force now comes from one pontoon. The differential moment is much smaller since additional tilt does not change the relative amount of each pontoon that is submerged. Is that what you meant?

Comment: During training for the latest AC a crew member died in a likely pitch pole capsize accident. The foiling boats are operated at the very limit of stability - you have to minimize anything that would make it worse. At these speeds (over 40 knots) a wave hitting a blunt now would mean certain disaster. See also http://youtu.be/drgglIebuQY (nobody died that time...). The dynamics of these boats are hard to control, but a sharp now helps. A bit.

Comment: @Floris I'm speaking strictly roll stability, not pitch in the case of lifting a pontoon. The effective water plane and moment arm is larger with both pontoons in the water. When one pontoon lifts there is sudden reduction of the width of the water plane, and thus restoring torque due to buoyancy. Metacentric height plummets. In this state even a small gust can blow the ship over (in roll).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at pictures of the boats in action you'll notice that they have hydrofoils and so the hull shape is only important at slow speed: in maneuvers or very light wind.

Having said that I would guess that the hull shape is to help minimise [wave drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave-making_resistance), which is fairly significant, especially as you approach foiling speeds.

Firstly, a more pointed shape helps pierce the waves and generally reduces wave making drag.
Secondly, having an inverted tilt on the bows could help increase the effective length of the boat and the period of any wave produced. Wave friction scales rapidly with speed/length. Therefore, increasing the length of the boat helps decrease wave friction (obviously at a cost of increased skin drag and weight).

When near to planing/hydrofoil speeds wave drag is probably dominant, as it scales much faster than skin drag which is the other main drag component. Therefore it is most beneficial to minimise the wave drag.